# Combobox Selected Item WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get selected item in combobox wpf. But it returns System.Data.DataRowView. My code in xaml :

```
<ComboBox Name="ddDeputi" Margin="131,85,0,0" Width="327" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Path = kodeDep, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="ddDeputi_SelectionChanged" Loaded="ddDeputi_Loaded" />
```

And in my .cs :

```
   private void ddDeputi_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ddDeputi.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            string akode = ddDeputi.SelectedValue.ToString();
            DaUnitKerja oDa = new DaUnitKerja();
            DataSet data = new DataSet();
            data = oDa.TampilDir(akode);
            ddDir.ItemsSource = data.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            ddDir.DisplayMemberPath = data.Tables[0].Columns["unit_kerja"].ToString();
            ddDir.SelectedValuePath = data.Tables[0].Columns["kode"].ToString();
            ddSubDir.SelectedIndex = -1;
            ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)ddDeputi.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ddDeputi.SelectedItem);
            txtDeputi.Text = cbi.Content.ToString();



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind to ADO.NET you are always data-binding to a DataView. Each DataRowView wraps a DataRow in the source DataTable

You can get the selected DataRow via the following:

```
DataRowView selectedDataRowView = (DataRowView)ddDir.SelectedItem;
DataRow selectedRow = selectedDataRowView.Row;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have defined selection changed event u can easily get any value from the table you bind to ddDeputi by the index value ....
Use comboBox1.SelectedIndex for the table index in event ddDeputi_SelectionChanged..

Like this

```
String value = data.Tables[0].Rows[ddDeputi.SelectedIndex]["kode"].ToString();
```

and the other way is cast your combo box selected item in comboboxitem and use it

```
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem currentItem=((System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem)ddDeputi.SelectedItem);

  string  myvalue=currentItem.Content;
```

Here myvalue gives u the selected value.