# INSERT INTO MySQL through C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am making a `WPF C#` exc. I have a `DAO` class, with connection to my Database and also Service class, with some methods for getting information from Database. It works fine. But i want to insert to database also. So, where is my mistake? I have method in Service class with that code

```
public static DataTable createProject(string projectName, string depName, string empName, int estTime, DateTime startDate)
{
   string sql = "";
   sql += "INSERT INTO Projects (projectName, departmentName, employeeName, estimatedTime, startDate)";
   sql += "VALUES (" + projectName + depName + empName + estTime + startDate +")";

   return getDataTable(sql);
}
```

And after that, i am going to my xaml.cs

```
private void btnCreateAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Service.createProject((string)txtProjName.Text, (string)cmbCreateDepartment.SelectedItem, (string)cmbCreateEmployees.SelectedItem, Int32.Parse(txtElapseTime.Text), (DateTime)Calendar.SelectedDate);
}
```

It gives me some exeption in my xaml.cs

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346481/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-data-datarowview-to-type-system-string

Comment: In which line you are getting the exception, put a breakpoint and check

Comment: at Service.createProject() line

Answer (score 1):

Look at the type of `cmbCreateDepartment.SelectedItem` and `cmbCreateEmployees.SelectedItem` attributes. It's a `System.Data.DataRowView` and not a `String` ! so the exception is logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void btnCreateAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
Service.createProject((string)txtProjName.Text, ((ComboBoxItem)cmbCreateDepartment.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(), ((ComboBoxItem)cmbCreateEmployees.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(), Int32.Parse(txtElapseTime.Text), (DateTime)Calendar.SelectedDate);
}
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'. This Exception

Comment: @Vladson cmbCreateDepartment i hope this is ComboBox name.?

Comment: @Vladson Then there is binding mistake.please go through this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420300/combobox-selected-item-wpf-c-sharp

Comment: Now i have this error : There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values
specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in 
the VALUES clause must match the number of columns 
specified in the INSERT statement. But i have the right number of columns

Comment: try using this sql = "INSERT INTO Projects VALUES('" + projectName +"','"+ depName +"','"+empName +"','"+ estTime +"','"+startDate +"')";